# Knowing from which machine ListenHTTP processor is receiving request

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a nifi pipeline which looks like this:

```
(LisitenHTTP)-[success]->(EvaluateJsonPath)-[failure,unmatched]->(ExecuteStreamCommand)       
                                |  
                            [matched]
                                |
                                V
                        rest of the pipeline
```

So, basically `ListenHTTP` receives a processing request (as json) on one of the ports. It forwards it to `EvaluateJsonPath` which decides how to process. However, if it fails to parse input json, it sends the flow file to `ExecuteStreamCommand` which logs failure notifications to dashboard.

Recently we were receiving large number of failure notifications on dashboards, even though whole system is working fine. So I was guessing whats going wrong. I checked the data provenance of `ExecuteStreamCommand` and realized that we were getting many invalid requests most of them were not even in json format. So I was trying to find how can we know from where we were getting these dummy requests. Is there any way to know from where we were getting these requests, may be IP of the machine sending these requests? Is there any way to enable detailed logging on `ListenHTTP` processor so that we get to know IP / hostname of machine logging such requests? Also can anyone think of any other way to fix this?

Comment: ListenHTTP could catch http headers. If your nifi behind some firewall, then you could setup firewall to provide some useful headers like client-ip

Answer (score 1):

Mahesha999,

This information is available in the request header: [X-Forwarded-For](http://X-Forwarded-For)  and [X-Forwarded-Host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host)

As @daggett pointed out if you have a firewall setup, you can setup the firewall to pass these headers along or map  them to some other thing like "client-ip"